# EC2 Database through Laravel Forge has stopped being accessable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1, forge

I've been running an instance EC2 through Laravel forge for about 2000 hours and this morning got this error while trying to reach it:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is
>   the server running on host "172.**.**.***" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

After SSHing into the server I've getting a similar error when trying to run a command. I've dug through AWS but don't see any errors being throw. I double checked the ip address for the instance to make sure the IP hadn't changed for any reason.  Of course I'm a little behind on my backups for the application so I'm hoping someone might have some ideas why else I can do to try and access this data. I haven't made any changes to the app in about 10 days, but found the error while I was pushing an update.  I have six other instances of the same app that weren't affected (thankfully) but makes me even more confused with the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across a similar issue, here's what had happened. I had an error running in the background which had filled up the EC2 harddrive's log. Since the default Larvel/Forge image has a DB running within in the EC2 instance, once it ran out of room everything stopped working. I was able to SSH in and delete the log though, and everything started working again.

To prevent the issue from happening again I then created an amazon RDS and used that rather than the EC2 instance.  It's about three or four times the price of just an EC2 instance, but still not that much and the confidence I now have in the system is well worth it.